# Python Subprocess to Pass yes / No

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have command which asks for input "YES". How do I pass this answer automatically?

I have used below code and it's not working.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
foo_proc = Popen([cmd], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
yes_proc = Popen(['YES'], stdout=foo_proc.stdin)
foo_output = foo_proc.communicate()[0]
yes_proc.wait()
```

Error that I am getting:

```
echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

PS: I am using python2.7

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to use the simple piped commands directly in Popen statement. You can use the following -

```
foo_proc = Popen(['echo' , 'yes', '|', cmd])
```

You need to use `shell=True`, e.g.

```
foo_proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo yes | conda install pyqtgraph'], shell=True)
```

For more details refer [(this link)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240513/pass-a-value-for-an-input-prompt)

Comment: I am getting error: foo_proc = Popen(['echo YES |', cmd], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply "conda install -y pyqtgraph"?

Ah, sorry, I've just understood it is an example.

Answer (score 0):

For CLI interaction I would use a Python module for controlling interactive programs in a pseudo-terminal like [Pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect).

It would allow you to perform similar and more complex tasks:

```
# This connects to the openbsd ftp site and
# downloads the recursive directory listing.
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('noah@example.com')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('lcd /tmp')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('cd pub/OpenBSD')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('get README')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('bye')
```

You can find its documentation [here](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

(Note this is python3 - python2 is EOL)

Just pass the 'YES' into communicate (don't forget the newline).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
foo_proc = Popen([cmd], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True)
foo_proc.communicate('YES\n')
```

If you'd rather use byte-strings, remove `text=True` and prefix `b` to the string within communicate. I.e.:

```
foo_proc = Popen([cmd], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
foo_proc.communicate(b'YES\n')
```